# vscode: We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name - file does exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

I'm debugging a ReactJS frontend but vscode is refusing to bind the breakpoint. On inspection it reports:

> This breakpoint was initially set in:
> C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\patches\src\components\Support\Products\XmlDetails\index.js line
> We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name:
> [random files here]

I think fair enough so the first thing I do is take that path and put it into the terminal:

```
C:\Users\grant>type C:\Users\grant\Documents\code\patches\src\components\Support\Products\XmlDetails\index.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import http from "../../../http";
import XmlTreeComponents from "./VersionViewer";
import "./style.css";
import TreeView from "@mui/lab/TreeView";
import TreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";
...SNIP...
```

this leaves me a bit perplexed as it is saying it can't find the file however the path it says it's looking for is 100% correct.

Here is my debugging configuration:

```
        {      
            "name": "Run Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://<IP>",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
```

The website itself comes up just fine and I have turned off cert checking (vscode will issue an error if you are running self signed certs and have it turned on).

```
    "debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions":  {
        "https": { "rejectUnauthorized": false } 
    }
```